# Paramaters with the same value - android

Tags: android, parameters

I have a listview that shows this paramaters. But 2 of the parameters returns the same value? How can I differentiate this two? Its email and voucher.

```
VoucherObj obj = new VoucherObj();
obj.customerID=item[0];
obj.type=item[1];
obj.name=item[2];
obj.searchStr=item[3];          <---- SAME PARAMETER
obj.searchStr=item[4];          <---- SAME PARAMETER
obj.branch=item[5]; 
obj.issued=item[6];
obj.expiration=item[7];
obj.status=item[8];
obj.vouchername=item[9];
obj.employeeid=item[10];    

items.add(obj);
```

Voucher.class

```
    public class VoucherObj {

public String customerID="";
public String type="";
public String name="";
public String email="";
public String voucher="";
public String branch="";
public String issued = "";
public String expiration="";
public String status = "";
public String vouchername = "";
public String employeeid = "";
public String searchStr;
```

}

Comment: you are assigning value of item[3] and item[4] to same variable obj.searchStr ??

Comment: Declare the `searchStr` field of your `VoucherObj` class as an `array` so you can append it as many values as you need.

Comment: @nKn how can I do that?

Comment: Do you have control to `VoucherObj`? Can you change the implementation of it? If it's always as you said (email and voucher), maybe it's better to change the field name to `email` and `voucher` too, unless `serachStr` can have arbitrary values, which nKn has answered.

Comment: yes its in voucherObj class. the problem is the email and voucher has the same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll have a static amount of items, you can declare the `searchStr` field of your `VoucherObj` as a static `array` with a fixed size. Assuming you're storing `String`s, this would be:

```
String[] searchStr = new String[10];
```

If the number of items of that field is unknown, just use a more advanced data structure, for instance:

```
ArrayList<String> searchStr = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Afterwards you can use this method to add a value:

```
obj.searchStr.add("value1");
obj.searchStr.add("value2");
...
```

Comment: its not static. it has multiple return from web

Comment: I posted the voucher class where I declare strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class VoucherObj(){
      int customerId;
      ..............
      ..............
      ArrayList<String> searchStr;
      ..............
      /*other parameters here*/

}
```

and in your main class use

```
obj.searchStr.add(item[3]);
obj.searchStr.add(item[4]);
```